# Selenium - counter of html elements

Tags: java, html, selenium, count, element

I've run into a problem which I do not how to solve.

```
<ul id="dropdownSelectRole" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">admin</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to count the number of `<li>` elements in order to put it to int and use in a while loop later on. 
Any advice (or ready code) how could I do that in java ?

Anyone please as well advice how to take the text value of each element to some list or table ?

I need to choose all the elements from above list (dropdown) to check that "Add" button will be inactive, afterwards delete all of the elements and check that "Add" is active. 
And after all press 'Add' button and choose only the elements that were before on the main list (kind of backup of initial data which were displayed before performing test).

Comment: Good question, I've been wondering that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownSelectRole"));
List<WebElement> list=element.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
int count = list.size();
```

"list" contains all the `<li>` elements and "count" contains the number.

Answer (score 2):

No need to store the number of `LI`s in an `int`, just loop through the elements themselves and act on them inside the loop, e.g. print the text, etc.

```
List<WebElement> lis = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#dropdownSelectRole > li"));
for (WebElement li : lis)
{
    System.out.println(li.getText().trim());
}
```

The CSS Selector, `#dropdownSelectRole > li`, means find an element with an id (#) dropdownSelectRole that has a child (>) `LI`.

If you really need to store the number of `LI`s, `int count = lis.size()`

For the other stuff you need to do for each element, add that code inside the loop and each task will be performed on each of those `LI` elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only need the number of li-elements, you can try this one-liner using xpath:

```
int count = findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id = 'dropdownSelectRole']/li")).size();
```